# CKAN Recline_view does not render Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error

Tags: ckan

recline_view view not rendering.

Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. error: An error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for URL

Answer (score 2):

It can't access the files since the data is not in the DataStore. You will need to set up the DataStore and use the DataPusher to import it. Check out the docs for it http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/datastore.html